# Line breaking after \paragraph{}

Tags: pdftex, line-breaking, paragraphs

I know that I can it with `\mbox{}\\` (`\paragraph{}\mbox{}\\`) but that's kinda messy and using `titlesec` to redefine `\paragraph{}` doesn't cut it for me either, because I most of the time want to have text right after the `\paragraph{}`. Is there any other way?

Comment: all latex headings can be declared as run-in or block, the standard classes declare paragraph as run-in but you can redeclare them by copying the the line and changing it or using a package such as titlesec to redeclare  the heading, but other classes like koma script or memoir have their own methods of declaring headings so the details depend on the class you are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All latex headings can be declared as run-in or block, the standard classes declare paragraph as run-in but you can redeclare them by copying the the line and changing it or using a package such as titlesec to redeclare the heading, but other classes like koma script or memoir have their own methods of declaring headings so the details depend on the class you are using.

If using the standard classes you can just copy the definition of `\paragraph` and change the signs of two arguments to make a display heading with no indent in the following text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% original definitions
%\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
%                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
%                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

%\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
%                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
%                                    {-1em}%
%                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\newcommand\dparagraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus-.2ex}% negative so no indent
                                    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}% positive so display heading
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dparagraph{Myparagraph} Some text.

\paragraph{Paragraph} Some text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want two different `\paragraph` formats. Try this:

```
% paraprob.tex SE 541902 newline or not after \paragraph
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

\begin{document}

\myparagraph{Myparagraph} Some text.

\paragraph{Paragraph} Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: hmm this would allow page breaking after the heading, and not allow the common input form of having a blank line before the paragraph text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, I would go with your superior knowledge.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just thought that my solution was simpler as it avoided messing with LaTeX internals.

Comment: I need an additional level in my headings structure, so I use \paragraph.
Unfortunately it does not look like my other headings - the horizontal space differs.

Definition of my `\subsubsection`:

    \RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}

Definition of my `\myparagraph`:

    \newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\ \hspace{0.25ex}}

Alternative definition (does not work, too):

    \RedeclareSectionCommands[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{myparagraph}

Can anybody help, please?