# Change font size and font type

Tags: fonts

Surprisingly I can't find direct answer to that.

Simply, I need global font Times New Roman (everything, sections, subsections, etc), and global size 12 pt.

I have managed to found potential answer for first question, which is `\usepackage{times}`, but I have heard you should not use it to change font to Times New Romand.

Edit

I also need very specific font size for sections only (14pt), but it seems to not be possible. You can only use `\large` etc to change font size. I guess word is not so bad after all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Using Times New Roman (1) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67768/times-new-roman-font

Comment: Using Times New Roman (2) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-do-i-make-my-document-use-the-times-font-both-for-the-text-and-the-math

Comment: What are LaTeX default font sizes? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155896/what-is-the-default-font-size-of-a-latex-document

Comment: Set font size of sections with `sectsty`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti/59727#59727

Comment: @musarithmia it contains conflicting informations, and now it won't compile at all.

Comment: Set specific font size by points: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57195/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-font-size-in-points?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please post a complete example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) even if it doesn't compile and then we can see how to help.

Comment: @musarithmia I had to change compiler. But now its Arial instead of Times New Roman (first link). Edit Ok no I think it actually works. But there is no way to set font size in points for specific type (section etc). Problematic, I really might be forced to use Word.

Comment: naturally you can set specific font sizes. But if you want sensible help you should show a complete minimal example.

Comment: It is possible to set specific point sizes, see above; but you can also use this information to see what point size the different size commands like `\large` actually produce: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1 . One of the cardinal rules of TeX, though, is that you shouldn't mess with layout in a time crunch. If you need to make a document very quickly and you aren't comfortable with this system, then by all means, use one you are more comfortable with.

Comment: @musarithmia writing more than 3-4 pages in Word is a mess. But I never realized switching a damn font size in Latex is harder than actual real programming. I guess I will have to add custom font size to every section. If I need to change it, I will just have to change dozens of lines. There is no other way it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `article` class with the `12pt` option, the `\large` command changes the font size to 14.4pt.

If you think someone is going to be measuring this with a ruler down to fractions of a point, then it is possible to define a command that gives you exactly 15pt (see the links in the comments under the question).

Compile this example with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\large} 

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works and at this point I'm too afraid to ask why. If you want to save me from suicide, you can also tell me how to create subsubsubsection. Titlesec solution on stackoverflow works, but paragraph body starts in the same line instead of in new line.

Comment: This example works because (1) calling article with 12pt options changes the overall font sizes to a default of 12pt, (2) the sectsty package provides commands that internally redefine LaTeX's macros to include whatever you say, so in this case it adds `\large` to the definition of a section, and (3) `fontspec` with XeLaTeX can load any font installed on your system.

Comment: There is no `\subsubsubsection` defined in LaTeX. If you really need that many levels of headings, and you need it to look different than default `\paragraph` heading, you cna change `\paragraph`; use the simplest solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541902/line-breaking-after-paragraph

Comment: it overrides font size and we are back at the start.

Comment: Wouldn’t you also want your math font to be Times, instead of the default Computer Modern? You’d want to load `unicode-math` for that.

Answer (score 2):

The currently-accepted answer will not change any of your math fonts from the default.  For that, you want a template like

```
\documantclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

Be aware that many Linux systems have a version of Times New Roman from last century, since that was the most recent version that Microsoft gave away for free. It should still work, but there are many other free clones of Times you could use.

You might also find XITS Math or STIX Two Math good Times-like math fonts.  This requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

In PDFLaTeX, the best way to get Times in text and math mode is:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
```

You might also try `stix` or `stix2`, or `tgpagella` plus `newtxmath`.

A “point” in TeX is not the same size as a “point” in your word processor, which TeX calls a `bp`.  An easier way to change to this size than the other answers gave you is

```
\usepackage[fontsize=12bp]{scrextend}
```