# Changing fonts - error message with fontspec package

Tags: xetex

I am getting the message "\msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}" with the following code. I am not sure what is wrong with the fontspec package. At the following website, it says to "Compile this example with xelatex."

```
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618838/change-font-size-and-font-type
```

I don't know what xelatex is. I just want to compile the same code in a couple of different fonts and a couple of different sizes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{lipsum}




\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

As David Carlisle stated, I do have an old LaTeX distribution. At his suggestion, I put `\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}` in the preamble and compiled it using PDFLaTeX. This time I got the following error message.

```
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason:
PK font ntx-Regular-tlf-tl could not be created.
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file ntx-Regular-tlf-tl): Font ntx-Regular -tlf-tl at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[16pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


Print this.



\lipsum[1]



\end{document}
```

In the log file, I get the following error messages.

```
2023-10-25 10:26:07,596-0400 INFO  texify - starting with command line: texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\File\Letter of Introduction.tex"

2023-10-25 10:43:37,177-0400 INFO  texify - starting with command line: texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\File\Letter of Introduction.tex"
```

Comment: you are using the command `pdflatex yourfile.tex` but you need to use `xelatex yourfile.tex` if you want to use xelatex and system fonts.

Comment: if you want to use pdflatex remove `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` and replace with `\usepackage{newtx}`

Comment: Now I get this error with `\usepackage{newtx}`.

Comment: `!LaTeX Error: File newtx.sty not found`

Comment: When I use `XeLaTeX` to compile the original file, I do not get any errors, but I also do not get the file to be typeset.

Comment: The file was typeset with xelatex, but yet no error? Odd. Can you trim the example down (remove "some packages") to something very small, that does the same thing? Maybe just load fontspec, the desired font (I hope you have Times new Roman installed where TeX can find it), and "Hello, World." as only document text.

Comment: @rallg I removed the unnecessary code from the preamble.

Comment: @user143462 you have an older latex distribution use `\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}` with pdflatex

Comment: @David Carlisle  I updated my post. Your suggested code is in the second half.

Comment: What is `16pt` doing in your call to `article`? There is no such option.

Comment: your tex distribution is very minimal or very messed up, you do not have many standard fonts installed, but you have not really said what you want to do, you could simply delete `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Times New Roman}` and not specify any non-default font at all. Certainly make sure that works first.

Comment: update in the miktex console (in user mode) the font maps: menu tasks -> refresh font map files.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer  I included the error messages that were reported in the log file at the end of my post - in case that is of any help.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer How do I get to the `miktex console`? I showed your message to a technician at a computer repair shop, and he didn't know about it. And this technician is the one who uploaded `miktex` onto my hard drive.

Comment: the miktex console is an application. You should find it in your start menu, or type miktex into the windows search.

Comment: Those are not errors. They are not from pdfTeX's log file. They look to be just information from texify about what it is doing. You'd need the actual log from the pdfTeX run to figure out what is/isn't going on. If the person who put MikTeX on your machine doesn't actually know anything about MikTeX, perhaps it is not configured correctly or important stuff didn't get installed?