# How to create subsubsubsection

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs

Default latex unfortunately is very limited, and it ends at 3 (for example 1.0.0). How to go one point further? (1.0.0.0)

There is solution somewhere on stackexchange that turns paragraph into subsubsubsections:

```latex
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

But results are far from expected.

How it should look:

```
1.0.0.0 Title
Body of paragraphs is here and it works fine
```

How it looks in reality:

```
1.0.0.0 Title Body of paragraphs is here and 
it looks terrible
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Did you see the posting [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209/5001) and [this associated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60218/5001)? [shameless self-citation alert]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541902/line-breaking-after-paragraph

Comment: @Mico results are identical (isn't it the same code?)

Comment: @musarithmia font size gets overriden and there is no way to change it.

Comment: Absolutely not. First, your code uses the `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing*` macros, whereas mine (cross-referenced above) redefines `\paragraph` directly, via a `\renewcommand` instruction. Second, can you spot the difference between `3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex` and `-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex`?

Comment: @Mico ok I got the wrong code. Now it won't compile.

Comment: @Mico ok it compiles but font size is also overriden.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by “font size is also overri[d]den.” Which font size is in use? (Both `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph` should use `\normalsize`.)

Comment: @Mico `\paragraphfont{\large}` for section titles, i have it set for `section`, `subsection`, and `subsubsection`. I need the same thing for our fake `subsubsubsection`.

Comment: Find the part in the code that says `\normalsize` and replace it with `\large`.

Comment: @musarithmia thanks king.

Comment: @PeterParker - And how was I supposed to know that you want `\large` as the font size for all sectioning commands? Sadly, but maybe not surprisingly, my mind-reading skills are absolutely rubbish.

Comment: you are mistaken the standard classes all have two further levels of heading below subsubsection, `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` (don't be fooled by the names which are just chosen to make it more readable than repeated sub...)

Comment: why is the result "unexpected" ?  that is just a matter of expectation. Latex supports two styles of heading display and run-in the documentation for a document class will say what style it uses and in any case it is easy to change

Answer (score 7):

> Default latex unfortunately is very limited,

everything has limitations but latex is not as you describe

> and it ends at 3 (for example 1.0.0).

The standard `book` and `report` class has 6 levels of heading (chapter (0) through to subparagraph (5))  and `article` has 5 levels (missing chapter)

The level at which latex stops numbering headings is set by the counter `secnumdepth` which `article` sets to 3 so you want

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

Then as documented `\paragraph` uses a run-in style you could use a package such as titlesec to declare it as a display heading, or simply copy the defintions from `article.cls` but change the sign to denote a display.

```
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
% display heading, like subsubsection
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
% display heading, like subsubsection
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{aaa}
aaa

\subsection{aaa}
aaa

\subsection{aaa}
aaa


\paragraph{aaa}
aaa

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi David, it seems I couldn't get `\subsubparagraph` work. It reported `Undefined control sequence. ^^I\subsubparagraph` when I tried to use it.

Comment: @Frank typo sorry fixed. subparagraph  is level  5

Answer (score 3):

You could use one of the KOMA-classes. They have a number of tools to adapt the sectioning commands

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=false,afterskip=0pt,afterindent=false]{paragraph}
\begin{document}
\section{abc}
some text
\paragraph{paragraph} 
some text 
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you should stop to believe that everything that doesn't look like you want it is "terrible". run-in headers are used in many places.

Comment: It won't compile with article document class.
Yeah I should choose my words more carefully, but I have spent last 2 hours doing this, and in Word it can be done in 30 seconds, so I'm really close to moving to south america and becoming a farmer.

Comment: well it only took me a minute to write the code above. And I could do it in a minute in other classes too. But you didn't provide a complete example and so nobody knows which class you are actually using. Be aware that LaTeX has a 30 year history, and so there are often various methods to achieve a goal.

Comment: @PeterParker From your questions and your comments on them that sounds like a good idea to me --- GOM